# China aid to development edict

Tags: tropico-4

Señorita Piña is asking me to proclaim this edict to "get more men", but I can't find it.  Only USSR and US development aid edicts are in the international relations pane.  Any one know how to activate the edict or accomplish the task?

Comment: Do you have an immigration office? How are your relations with China?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The China dev aid edict is part of the Modern Times set of edicts.

(Warning: You'll get a hundred uneducated Chinese immigrants on the next boat; if you don't have housing/employment for them, your popularity's going to take a nosedive.)

Comment: Thanks.  Weird think, I have the Modern Times extension, but I was not playing the Modern Times campaign and thus no way to complete the task.  I guess this is a bug.